# strange hashing match all the time in bash scripting

Tags: bash, hash

```
    #!/bin/bash
    guess=`awk '{print $1}' password`
    try=$(echo "$guess" | sha256sum)
    testing="f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2"
    if [" $try "==" $testing "]
    then
        echo "the password is $guess"
    else
        echo "password not found"
    fi
```

So i am trying to get first line value from password file, and using sha256sum to get the hashing value, and compare the hashing value with the value that i already given, if they are the same, it means i found the password. However, when i try to run it, it became crazy, if i set first value in password to be "abc", the output will be "the password is abc", if i set the value to be "hello", output will be hello. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: have you tried spitting out `$try` as well? see what you're getting back from the sha call.

Comment: `if [" $try "==" $testing "]` has syntax issues

Comment: @anubhava u mean i need to do if[ ];then..., something like this? I tried this as well and also i used spellcheck, it didn't give me any errors or warnings

Comment: No, he means you need `if [ "$try" == "$testing" ]`. The spaces need to be around the `[`, `]`, and `==`. See http://www.shellcheck.net/ .

Comment: @MarcB i tried to run the code for $try line by line in terminal, and it gave me what i need, however if i put it together , it makes me crazy

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh yess!!!! It works... thank you so much..

Comment: @anubhava thank you sir, i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
  if [" $try "==" $testing "]
```

this code has syntax errors, i should not make space between " and $try,$testing also i need to give space between " and ==.

Corrected:

```
  if [ "$try" == "$testing" ]
```

Comment: Showing the corrected code in the answer instead of the erroneous code from the question is a better idea (both is fine too if you prefer).