# how to use a loop to get data from file one by one in scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

```
test abc bcd
```

so i have a file named "password", and i tried to get values one by one to do some testing.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in '1..5' 
do
guess=`awk '{print $i}' password`
try=$(echo "$guess" | sha256sum)
testing="f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2"
if [" $try "==" $testing "]
then
    echo "the password is $guess"
else
    echo "password not found"
fi
done
```

so i was thinking to use this for loop to get values, however i got errors for the for loop, and i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Why are you still using the same incorrect quoting that you asked about (and self-answered) in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32336097/1126841)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistakes in your script, bash by default separate based on white spaces, also string comparison is different in bash than other programming languages.

reference: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

This code will resolve your issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
for guess in `cat password`; 
do
    try=$(echo "$guess" | sha256sum|awk '{print $1}')
    testing="f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2"
    if [ "$try" = "$testing" ]
    then
        echo "the password is $guess"
    else
        echo "password not found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the dictionary in linux(/usr/share/dict/linux.words)? I need to do dictionary attack after normal password checking(this is for my assignment, not hacking). I don't know how to use it, and i searched it online, still don't know how to use the dictionary. @Umer